# Python: Passing mutable(?) object to method

Tags: python, object, methods, arguments, mutable

I'm trying to implement a class with a method that **calls another method with an object that's part of the class where the lowest method mutates the object**. My implementation is a little more complicated, so I'll post just some dummy code so you can see what I'm talking about:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.obj = list
    def mult(self, x, n):
        x = x*n
    def numtimes(self, n):
        self.mult(self.obj, n)
```

Now, if I create an object of this type and run the numtimes method, it won't update self.obj:

```
m = test([1,2,3,4])
m.numtimes(3)
m.obj  #returns [1,2,3,4]
```

Whereas I'd like it to give me [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]

Basically, I need to pass self.obj to the mult method and have it mutate self.obj so that when I call m.obj, I'll get [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4] instead of [1,2,3,4].

I feel like this is just a matter of understanding how python passes objects as arguments to methods (like it's making a copy of the object, and instead I need to use a pointer), but maybe not. I'm new to python and could really use some help here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers; when you pass a variable to a function, you're just binding the function parameter to the same value that the variable is bound to. If that's a mutable value, you can mutate it. Your problem is that `x = whatever` just rebinds the local variable `x`, it doesn't mutate anything.

Comment: Meanwhile, do you really need to mutate `self.obj` in-place? If `mult` just did `return x*n`, and `numtimes` did `self.obj = self.mult(self.obj, n)`, would that work? That isn't appropriate for every use case (e.g., if `self.obj` is a 10000x10000 matrix, you may not want to make an extra copy; if some other code has a reference to `self.obj` and needs to see the change, making a copy won't help)… but when it is, it's often simpler.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. In retrospect, I think I should have also included an array element assignment in 'mult' because that's really the most important operation I'm trying to do. I just used 'x=x*n' for simplicity but I realize it confused things a bit. I really need to change the elements of 'self.obj' according to some logic in the 'mult' method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to take on the bigger subject of mutability.

Lists are mutable objects, and support both mutable operations, and immutable operations. That means, operations that change the list in-place, and operations that return a new list. Tuples, for contrast, only are only immutable.

So, to multiply a list, you can choose two methods:

1. **a *= b**

This is a **mutable** operation, that will change 'a' in-place.

1. **a = a * b**

This is an **immutable** operation. It will evaluate 'a*b', create a new list with the correct value, and assign 'a' to that new list.

Here, already, lies a solution to your problem. But, I suggest you read on a bit. When you pass around lists (and other objects) as parameters, you are only passing a new reference, or "pointer" to that same list. So running mutable operations on that list will also change the one that you passed. The result might be a very subtle bug, when you write:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> t = test(my_list)
>>> t.numtimes(2)
>>> my_list
[1,2,3,1,2,3]  # Not what you intended, probably!
```

So here's my final recommendation. You can choose to use mutable operations, that's fine. But then create a new copy from your arguments, as such:

```
def __init__(self,l):
    self.obj = list(l)
```

OR use immutable operations, and reassign them to self:

```
def mult(self, x, n):
    self.x = x*n
```

Or do both, there's no harm in being extra safe :)

Comment: Is there a mutating array assignment operation? So, say can I pass self.obj as an argument to mult, where I copy part of it into a dummy list and recopy a (sorted) version back to self.obj, such that I can access the sorted version of self.obj outside of that method later?

Comment: Are you looking for mutable "assignment" to lists? Because that's possible: my_list[:] = [1,2,3,4]

Also, you can use slicing to alter part of a list, i.e. change the last three elements:  my_list[-3:] = [1,2,3]

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication `x * n` creates a new instance and does not alter the existing list. See here:

```
a = [1]
print (id (a) )
a = a * 2
print (id (a) )
```

This should work:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,list):
        self.obj = list

    def mult(_, x, n):
        x *= n

    def numtimes(self, n):
        self.mult(self.obj, n)
```

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't really explain the difference between `x = x*n` and `x *= n`. The first one just calls `x.__mult__(n)`, which should be a non-mutating function, and assigns the result to `x`, which doesn't affect anyone else who has a reference to the original value (like the caller). The second one calls `x.__imult__(n)`, which should be mutating if possible, which means it _does_ affect someone else who has a reference to the original value. Or maybe just show `a *= 2; print(id(a))` instead of trying to explain the details.